# Regular Expression Matching with Carriage Returns in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following data and want to match certain strings as commented below.

```
FTUS80 KWBC 081454 AAA\r\r TAF AMD   #should match 'AAA'
LTUS41 KCTP 082111 RR3\r\r TMLLNS\r  #should match 'RR3' and 'TMLLNS'
SRUS55 KSLC 082010\r\r HM5SLC\r\r    #should match 'HM5SLC'
SRUS55 KSLC 082010\r\r SIGC  \r\r    #should match 'SIGC  ' including whitespace
```

I need the following conditions met. But it doesn't work when I put it all together so I know I have mistakes. Thanks in advance.

- Start match after 6 digit string: (?<=\d{6})
- match if 3 character mixed uppercase/digits and before first 2 carriage returns: ([A-Z0-9]{3})(?=\r)
- match if 6 characters mixed uppercase/digits after carriage returns: (?<=\r\r[A-Z0-9]{6})
- match if 4 characters and two spaces: ([A-Z0-9]{4}  )

Comment: Are the `\r` characters in your example data representative of actual carriage returns or are you getting the actual characters `\r` returned as placeholders for carriage returns in the original data?

Comment: @benvc Actual CRs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant way, but you could do something like the following:

```
(?:\d{6}\s?)([A-Z\d]{3})?(?:[\r\n]{2}\s)([A-Z\d]{6}|[A-Z\d]{4}\s{2})?
```

- `(?:\d{6}\s?)` non capture group of 6 digits followed by an optional space
- `([A-Z\d]{3})?` optional capture group of 3 uppercase letters / digits
- `(?:[\r\n]{2}\s)` non capture group of two line endings followed by 1 space
- `([A-Z\d]{6}|[A-Z\d]{4}\s{2})?` optional capture group of either 6 uppercase letters / digits OR 4 uppercase letters / digits followed by 2 spaces

Comment: What if there are more than 2 carriage returns, like [link](https://regex101.com/r/Nnx1GX/3)? It doesn't match 2 CRs so I put in 4 and that kinda works but still doesn't match 'SIGC  '. How are CRs counted?

Comment: @klex52s - if the number of spaces, carriage returns, line endings are not consistent, then use a less precise quantifier. Something like: `(?:\d{6}\s*)([A-Z\d]{3})?(?:[\r\n\s]+)([A-Z\d]{6}|[A-Z\d]{4}\s{2})?`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what's the end of line here but assuming it's Unix one `\n`, the following expression captures strings as requested (double quotes added to show white space)

```
sed -rne 's/^.{18} ?([A-Z0-9]{3,3})?\r{2}?([^\r]+)?\r.*$/"\1\2"/p' text.txt
```

Result

```
"AAA"
"RR3 TMLLNS"
" HM5SLC"
" SIGC  "
```

- `.{18}` first 18 characters
- `?([A-Z0-9]{3,3})?` matches AAA or RR3 without leading space
- `\r{2}?([^\r]+)?\r` matches `TMLLNS`, `HM5SLC` or `SIGC` preceded by 2 `\r` and followed by 1 `\r` characters.